# Why root and status is null in transaction receipts

Tags: web3js, parity

I deployed a smart contract on my private Parity node with Web3js. I got transaction hash and logs those I submitted at my contract creation. Everything works well, I can call functions correctly. However, I found `root` and `status` are always null. Do I need to notice anything when I setup private Parity nodes?

and here is my transaction receipt

```
{
  "blockHash": "0x01c6f939be54648c88ef1d4fac47566cb9b547e417f0349aa906727e452ff00d",
  "blockNumber": 47327,
  "contractAddress": "0x1dCd376E72Ba525ABbd3eD6c60Bab965755D9877",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 3198406,
  "from": "0x452e132dad56f288b0bbbd956b064778578cfc71",
  "gasUsed": 3198406,
  "logs": [
    {
      "address": "0x1dCd376E72Ba525ABbd3eD6c60Bab965755D9877",
      "blockHash": "0x01c6f939be54648c88ef1d4fac47566cb9b547e417f0349aa906727e452ff00d",
      "blockNumber": 47327,
      "data": "0x000000000000000000000000452e132dad56f288b0bbbd956b064778578cfc71",
      "logIndex": 0,
      "removed": false,
      "topics": [
        "0x041109cfe10cfa549abb66b986d0a294ecc6c9ad39000abcb9c2afd422c8bd64"
      ],
      "transactionHash": "0xffa363046e6d07e316979c1fb5d32171751af5315b50e81dc8e43beb6be2eea0",
      "transactionIndex": 0,
      "transactionLogIndex": "0x0",
      "type": "mined",
      "id": "log_1bbacac5"
    },
    {...}
  ],
  "logsBloom": "0x04000000200000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000",
  "root": null,
  "status": false,
  "to": null,
  "transactionHash": "0xffa363046e6d07e316979c1fb5d32171751af5315b50e81dc8e43beb6be2eea0",
  "transactionIndex": 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you should care about `root`, but `status` should be either `0x0` (failure) or `0x1` (success), according to the specs (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt). It's weird that you have it set to `false`. Are you sure you have Byzantium (the EIP that introduces the `status` field) enabled on your chain? You might want to look into https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/7124 for Byzantium-specific configuration changes.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Actually, I don't care `status` but Web3js does. If `status` is null, I'll get tx result from `error` callback not the normal one.